# How to use React Ref with Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am running React 16.8.6 and Styled Components 4.3.2 currently and am hitting an issue trying to use React.forwardRef.

In Comments.js

```
import CommentItem from './CommentItem';
class Comments extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.items = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.items);
  }

  render() {
    const { comments } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
          {comments.length > 0 &&
            comments.map((comment, i) => {
              this.items[i] = React.createRef();
              return (
                <CommentItem
                  ref={this.items[i]}
                  key={comment.id}
                  comment={comment}
                />
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In CommentItem.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Media } from "react-bulma-components";

const CommentMediaWrapper = styled(Media)`
  position: relative;
`;
const CommentItem = React.forwardRef(
  ({ comment }, ref) => {
    return (
      <CommentMediaWrapper ref={ref}>
        <div>...</div>
      </CommentMediaWrapper>
    );
  }
);
export default CommentItem;
```

In Comments.js will console an array `[{ current: null },...]`
I don't know how to pass ref in to `CommentMediaWrapper`. I don't want add new element outer or inner `CommentMediaWrapper`. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue here is more to do with the library element `Media` from `react-bulma-components` that you are wrapping. This component exposes a prop named `domRef` that can be used to pass the DOM reference to the HTML element underneath the wrappers.

```
const CommentItem = React.forwardRef(
  ({ comment }, ref) => {
    return (
      <CommentMediaWrapper domRef={ref}>
        <div>...</div>
      </CommentMediaWrapper>
    );
  }
);
```

[Github Reference](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components/blob/c86b175c39d7c3a5cf84ca2a884a76b4c3705e0a/src/components/element/element.js#L12)

Comment: thank for your help, I check document and see every Element will receice props **domRef**, but when I give **domRef** prop it still don't work.